# Join two pandas dataframes on timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes, identical in columns. Each have a timestamp column. One dataframe has text data from user A and another dataframe has text data from user B. When user A is speaking, user B is not speaking, so the data never overlaps. I want to merge them together into one dataframe organized by timestamp.

```html
df_a

    start  stop                         words
      0      2.1         i know honey but what happened we got a job
      3.7    6.4         no know but thats a different kind of help but
      8.2   11.5         because people that are supposed to be
      12.9  15.4         yeah but where else can you go to get one
           
df_b

    start  stop                         words
      2.2   3.6            but he never said
      6.5   8.2            but what?
     11.6   12.8           i dont think thats true
     15.5   19.2           anywhere i dont know
     
desired_output

    start  stop                         words
      0     2.1         i know honey but what happened we got a job
      2.2   3.6         but he never said
      3.7   6.4         no know but thats a different kind of help but
      6.5   8.2         but what?
      8.2   11.5        because people that are supposed to be
      11.6  12.8        i dont think thats true
      12.9  15.4        yeah but where else can you go to get one
      15.5  19.2        anywhere i dont know
```

Comment: This is technically not a join but a concatenation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
df = df_a.append(df_b).sort_values(by=['start'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `pd.concat` given the operation feels more like concatenating rather than joining:

```
output = pd.concat([df_a,df_b]).sort_values(['start'])
print(output)
   start  stop                                           words
0    0.0   2.1     i know honey but what happened we got a job
0    2.2   3.6                               but he never said
1    3.7   6.4  no know but thats a different kind of help but
1    6.5   8.2                                       but what?
2    8.2  11.5          because people that are supposed to be
2   11.6  12.8                         i dont think thats true
3   12.9  15.4       yeah but where else can you go to get one
3   15.5  19.2                            anywhere i dont know
```

Comment: beat me to it, nice one :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I was about to post it myself!